K6 running out of memory because of metrics during load test
When i run my k6 test for a long period of time I run out of memory. I get warnings telling me that I am accumulating a large amount of metrics, and i believe that to be the problem, as the memory slowly rises over a long period of time. When running the test for 40 min it was using 100GB ram, so i dont think i can simply scale the machine running the test.
The exact warning i am getting is:
WARN[0027] The test has generated metrics with 100163 unique time series, which is higher than the suggested limit of 100000 and could cause high memory usage. Consider not using high-cardinality values like unique IDs as metric tags or, if you need them in the URL, use the name metric tag or URL grouping. See https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/using-k6/tags-and-groups/ for details.  component=metrics-engine-ingester

I have tried following the suggestion and put tags on my calls, i dont know if i am doing it incorrectly, or if it simply does not work on POST requests. The api i am load testing is quite different as everything on it is in form of a POST request, so i also suspect that could be a problem.
Here is an example of one of the calls i make:
export function getData(userInfo) {
    var url = GetUrl()
    var body = GetBaseBody(userInfo)
    body.cmd = "getDataCommand"

    var response = http.post(url.toString(), body, {
        tags: {group: 'PostsItemURL', name: 'PostsItemURL'},
    })
    return response.body.data
}

I do not need the metrics on the test, as it is used to provide a "base load" on the application. So i was wondering if there is a way to disable metrics, or at least make it so k6 does not hold them in memory?
I tried adding tags to the request, i expected that to give k6 an easier time grouping request together, making it take less memory, it seems to have done nothing.
I tried getting it to output metics to file, it does output the metrics to the file, but seems to also hold it in memory. I could not fully test this, as i would need to spin a large amount of load to really see, but on the small test i have done it did nothing.
I have looked into disabling insights, or metrics in general, I found out that you cannot outright disable it.
I have tried disabling the final report you get, hoping that would stop it from collecting the data, that did nothing aswell.
The whole scenarios options looks like this:
export const options = {
    userFileName: __ENV.MY_USER_FILE_NAME,
    scenarios: {
        standingOnFrontPage: {
            executor: 'ramping-vus',
            exec: 'standingOnFrontPage',
            gracefulStop: '30s',

            startVus: 1,
            stages: [
                {duration: __ENV.RAMPUP_TIME, target: __ENV.STANDING_FRONTPAGE_USERS},
                {duration: __ENV.STEADY_TIME, target: __ENV.STANDING_FRONTPAGE_USERS},

            ],
        },
        streamingContentFromFrontPage: {
            executor: 'ramping-vus',
            exec: 'streamingContentFromFrontPage',
            gracefulStop: '30s',

            startVus: 1,
            stages: [
                {duration: __ENV.RAMPUP_TIME, target: __ENV.STREAMING_FRONTPAGE_USERS},
                {duration: __ENV.STEADY_TIME, target: __ENV.STREAMING_FRONTPAGE_USERS},
            ],
        },
        streamingContentFromTvGuide: {
            executor: 'ramping-vus',
            exec: 'streamingContentFromTvGuide',
            gracefulStop: '30s',

            startVus: 1,
            stages: [
                {duration: __ENV.RAMPUP_TIME, target: __ENV.STREAMING_TVGUIDE_USERS},
                {duration: __ENV.STEADY_TIME, target: __ENV.STREAMING_TVGUIDE_USERS},
            ],
        }
    },
};


Here is an example of what an individual scenario looks:
export function streamingContentFromFrontPage() {
    sleep(2)
    var userInfo = getUserInfoFromList(data);

    var elementToWatch = loadFrontpageGetElementToWatch(userInfo);
    if (elementToWatch == null) {
    }

    sleep(Math.random() * 10)
    startAndWatchStream(userInfo, elementToWatch)
}

The calls that they are making all follow this pattern:


export function GetUrl() {
    var url = new URL("URL TO OUR BACKEND");
    return url
}

function GetBaseBody(userInfo) {

    return {
        //The body is required to always have certain fields such as timestamp or manufacture of device.
        "manufacturer": userInfo.manufacturer,
        "timestamp": ts,
    }

}

export function getData(userInfo) {
    var url = GetUrl()
    var body = GetBaseBody(userInfo)
    body.cmd = "getDataCommand"

    var response = http.post(url.toString(), body)
    return response.body.data
}

I have tried with, and without. the additional Tags, but it doesn't seem to be making a difference.
Sorry that i cannot be more specific than this, we have some security people that doesn't allow me to be more specific

I don't see where your function would be generating lots of unique metric values. Does GetUrl() return the same URL or a different URL every time? Are you heavily using the group() function? Can you show your whole script? Have you tried disabling or limiting the system tags? Why do you specify additional tags if the number of metrics is too high already?

@Adriaan tests for k6 are implemented with JavaScript, but in this case the question is specific to k6 and cannot be answered with JavaScript knowledge. Adding the JavaScript (or Go) tag would only distract from the real issue. The tags of the question are good as is ad I wouldn't add a language tag just for the sake of it.

@knittl I have added some more details, hope they help.

@MikkelJacobsen Thanks for the update! I don't see any red flags in the code. Just to double-check new URL("URL TO OUR BACKEND"); returns the same URL every time? Can you try with a regular string instead of an URL object? Can you try with a newer (or older) k6 version? I know that the metrics infrastructure was rewritten in one of the last few versions, maybe something broke there. But from the error message it sounds like something is creating lots of unique label values and I don't see this in your posted code.

@knittl Yes same URL every time. Tried with just a string and the test still works, but no difference in the amount of metrics. The older versions did not help either, I tried all the way back to v0.45.0.
I tried directing the metrics to a file, but seems like it holds the metrics in memory, as well as writing them to file. I dont know if the problem has something to do with the fact that every call is a post, and the body of the post changes on every request.

No, the body is not part of metric keys. Do you have lots of thresholds defined? Did you already try to limit or disable the system tags?

@knittl I dont have any thresholds defined, i tried adding "systemTags: []," to the options, as well as  "--no-thresholds --no-teardown --no-usage-report --no-summary" when i run it, but that made no difference.

Time series based metrics were introduced with k6 0.41 (https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/2765). Can you try 0.40 with your script? I know, it's old, but that way we can narrow down the issue. How many VUs is your test utilizing? I think the VU ids are also tracked as metric key. Related and potentially helpful: https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/2762

We are using at least 150k VUs. When I downgraded the version i got an error saying something about to many open files, i didn't have a lot of time to look into this, as optimizing the test i sadly no longer prioritized. We will simply throw more hardware at the problem instead of optimizing further. I did look at the github issues, and also found (https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/1321) when this is implemented ignoring a lot of the metrics should do the job

Okay, more than 150k VUs is A LOT. Assuming 1 MB memory usage per VU that's already 150GB. To summarize: not a lot that you can do currently, I think, besides opening an issue with k6 (I'm sure they are interested in hearing about your use case) or waiting for things to improve with upcoming versions due to general optimizations.

Have you looked into running distributed tests or using the cloud version of k6? The total memory consumption will be the same (likely slightly more even), but a single host/process won't be taking 100 gigs of memory.
